# android.support.v7.widget.CardView not being recognized

Tags: android, build.gradle, androidx

I'm trying to use older dependencies for my app and in the XML file it doesn't recognize the layout and it gives me an error. Moreover the build.gradle files compiles perfectly yet shows a red underline below the implementations of cardview and recyclerview.

Xml File:
Attached picture of what I need but yet isn't recognized.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZIbm.jpg
build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testsuccess"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.0'
}
```

I've even tried implementing

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7'
```

But it forces me to Migrate to Androidx libraries and doesn't allow me to use the old ones.
Note: the layout is an additional file in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the old class names, you need to disable the androidx from gradle.properties file using

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

Which forces the androidx to be disabled.

**OR**

Dont want to disable androidx.

Then replace this line

from

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

This will work fine in AndroidX.

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

This will bring in `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`, which is what your layout is looking to use.

Comment: But I would like to use the old format so I kinda actually asked the question. Sorry

Comment: @Kate: "But I would like to use the old format" -- why? The old artifacts are no longer being maintained.

Comment: This answer uses the most up-to-date methods at time of writing. This should be the accepted answer.